# Use of currrent() function on models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I found this code somewhere online.

```
$p = (new Participant())->current();
```

What does this do? I have a Participant model and currently logged in participant in my session in variable 'participant'.

I was not able to find any documentation for this.

Comment: It is not exists at Laravel default. Maybe you found this code from another codebase which is not about of your codes?

Comment: Is Participant derived directly from an Eloquent Model (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)? If so, then unless you've implemented 'current' yourself then this code won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current is a PHP function

Taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> current — Return the current element in an array

**Description**

```
mixed current ( array $array )
```

> Every array has an internal pointer to its "current" element, which is
>   initialized to the first element inserted into the array.

Example #1 Example use of current() and friends

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'plane';

$arr = array();
var_dump(current($arr)); // bool(false)

$arr = array(array());
var_dump(current($arr)); // array(0) { }
?>
```

---

Current ***is*** used in Laravel but it's used to access the current URL.

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();
```

---

Lastly, if you found the code somewhere online, current() could have been a method that was created to do something. I'd look more at the code you found and see if there is a current() method.

Answer (score 2):

That code simply creates a new instance of `Participant` and then calls its `current` method, assigning its result to the variable `$p`. It's effectively the same as doing this:

```
$participant = new Participant();
$p = $participant->current();
```

As for what the `current` method does is anyone's guess. I don't believe there's a `current` method in Laravel's `Model` class or any of its traits. If you've seen that online somewhere, it could be that the `current` method is implemented by that tutorial.